# apache virtual host definition with regex

Tags: regex, apache, vhosts

For development projects I point real domains to localhost using hosts file. and I add virtual host definition to apache config file. My question is it possible to redirect all "xyz.com" domains to "d:/xampp/htdocs/websites/xyz.com" directory ? this way I will not need to add vhost definition everytime.

Comment: I would like every *.com domain to go different folders under "D:/xampp/htdocs/websites/". mywebsite.com should go "D:/xampp/htdocs/websites/mywebsite.com". otherwebsite.com should go ""D:/xampp/htdocs/websites/otherwebsite.com""

Comment: You can edit your question to add this updated information instead of adding a comment.

Comment: I found that, this can be possible with mod_vhost_alias module, but I am not experienced with it. I will investigate, and when I find the solution I will post it here, for sharing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a wildcard in your `VirtualHost`'s `ServerAlias` directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Official name is example.com
  ServerName example.com

  # Any subdomain *.example.com also goes here
  ServerAlias *.example.com

  DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/websites/xyz.com"

  # Then rewrite subdomains into different directories
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example.com$
  # Use the %1 captured from the HTTP_HOST
  # For example abc.example.com writes to websites/abc.com
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "D:/xampp/htdocs/websites/%1.com/$1" [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I would like every *.com domain to go different folders under "D:/xampp/htdocs/websites/". mywebsite.com should go "D:/xampp/htdocs/websites/mywebsite.com". otherwebsite.com should go ""D:/xampp/htdocs/websites/otherwebsite.com""

Comment: @bkilinc Sorry I didn't have time to finish this earlier. I restored my answer along with rewrite rules that rewrite the subdomain into a directory name.