# .htaccess Rewrite "external" subdomain to subfolder if match

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Lets say i have wildcard subdomains on an external domain, can be anything like

demo.site1.com

blah.site1.com

and have directories like these on an external websites

external.com/websites/demo.site1.com

external.com/websites/blah.site1.com

and i want to make it so that all requests for lets say demo.site1.com should rewrite to

external.com/websites/demo.site1.com if the subdirectory matches demo.site1.com

NO REDIRECTION, I MUST KEEP THE URL THE SAME...

I have to do this for multiple subdomains with the same kind of subdirectories.

Is it possible to do?? if not is it possible without matching???

I read the apache .htaccess docs over and over for the past 12 hours and can't seem to

figure out a way how to do it.

Your help will mean alot to me...

Comment: see this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169843/apache-virtual-host-definition-with-regex

Comment: Its on shared hosting

Comment: what is `external.com` is a another domain of your share host ?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure Your domain in domain administration panel to point at this addresses.

If You don't have access to them use iframe, but as far I know .htaccess doesn't provide this kind of functionality.

Comment: can i do it even if it doesnt match?

Comment: Or what if the external websites are addon domains instead?

Comment: You should be able to do it anyway. Search You domain registrar FAQ/Help pages.

Answer (score 0):

try this. put it inside htaccess on `site1.com` document root. it work only if both domain has permission to access together

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.site1.com/(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ external.com/websites/$1.site1.com/$2 [L]
```