# Dynamic Virtual host in apache/nginx - proxy requests based on servername prefix

Tags: apache, nginx

Would like to add dynamic virtual hosts and rules to proxy web requests as follows

```
subdomain1.example.com/contexta  => subdomain1.appservera.internal.host
subdomain1.example.com/contextb  => appserverb.internal.host
subdomain1.example.com/contextc  => appserverc.internal.host
subdomain2.example.com/contexta  => subdomain2.appservera.internal.host
subdomain2.example.com/contextb  => appserverb.internal.host
subdomain2.example.com/contextc  => appserverc.internal.host
subdomain3.example.com/contexta  => subdomain3.appservera.internal.host
subdomain3.example.com/contextb  => appserverb.internal.host
subdomain3.example.com/contextc  => appserverc.internal.host
```

The generalized routing pattern is as shown below. The downstream server the request would be routed to is obtained from the prefix of the server name (only for some context roots though).

```
*.example.com/contexta  => *.appservera.internal.host
*.example.com/contextb  => appserverb.internal.host
*.example.com/contextc  => appserverc.internal.host
```

Ideally, when new subdomains are added, we would like Apache configuration to not change. Is that possible?

I looked into [Mass Virtual Hosting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html) but documentation was not clear.

If this is not a straightforward usecase, would nginx be more capable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work with `nginx`:

```
server {
  ...
  server_name "~^(?<name>.+)\.example\.com$";
  ...
  location /contexta {
    proxy_pass http://$name.appservera.internal.host/;
    ...
  }
  location /contextb {
    proxy_pass http://appserverb.internal.host/;
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

See [this documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) and [this documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for more information. I am sure it's equally easy to achieve with Apache.

Comment: Thanks, found more solutions to do dynamic url rewriting in Apache without needing to add virtual host. Here are some links:  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html and  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169843/apache-virtual-host-definition-with-regex